# text highlighting with sencha framework and getting that text?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

i have to develop an application with sencha touch in which user can highlight selected text in html document, add notes and bookmark.
please guide me where to start.
how to add these things to my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys i found the answer. i have searched the net 2 days and I found no option for doing these things in Sencha. when i saw this link 
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?122745-retreiving-selected-text-doesnt-work-in-htmlEditor-for-chrome-and-safari-browser

i decided to do this with javascript. You have to use old javascript and jquery to do these things till the time sencha adds new feature in it